# Replace last occurrence of a word within a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace last occurrence of a word within string.

This doesn't work:

```
var str = '@[Kenneth Auchenberg](contact:1) @[kenneth@auchenberg.dk](contact:7) Kenneth Auchenber';
v = str.replace(/Kenneth Auchenberg(?![sS]*Kenneth Auchenberg?)/ , '@[Kenneth Auchenberg](contact:1)');
alert(v);
```

This works fine, though:

```
var str = '-44-test alue-1564test alue';
str = str.replace(/test alue(?![\s\S]*test alue)/, 'aa');
alert(str);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/appdevd/rhp28/)

Why doesn't the first version work, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show what your desired **output** is? `Kenneth Auchenberg(?![sS]*Kenneth Auchenberg?)` matches the name not followed by esses and the name again, with an optional g. It's confusing, please tell us what **output** you want.

Comment: still no luck, http://jsfiddle.net/appdevd/rhp28/2/

Comment: The desired output is @[Kenneth Auchenberg](contact:1) @[kenneth@auchenberg.dk](contact:7) @[Kenneth Auchenberg](contact:1)

Comment: @DhruvPatel: The [regex you currently have](http://regex101.com/r/qV0xF1) seems to work fine, and I don't see what's wrong. Could you add clearer examples?

Comment: can you please edit the fiddle?

Comment: I think you misspelled the last bit of the string: Kenneth Auchenber', yet you are looking to replace "Kenneth Auchenberg"  --> no "g"

Comment: @Amal, 1st one should work!

Comment: @DhruvPatel: Oh, I misread your question. I've now edited it to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your input string and regexp code. 
First, modified `[\s\S]*Kenneth Auchenberg` and `g` was missing `Kenneth Auchenberg';`

```
var str = '@[Kenneth Auchenberg](contact:1) @[kenneth@auchenberg.dk](contact:7) Kenneth Auchenberg';
v = str.replace(/Kenneth Auchenberg(?![\s\S]*Kenneth Auchenberg?)/ , '@[Kenneth Auchenberg](contact:1)');
alert(v);

var str = '-44-test alue-1564test alue';
str = str.replace(/test alue(?![\s\S]*test alue)/, 'aa');
alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Search: `Kenneth Auchenberg?(?!g?\]|\(contact)`

Replace: `@[Kenneth Auchenberg](contact:1)`

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/pT8fF8).

Comment: @DhruvPatel Fixed bug, added demo. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure the name you wanna match is at the end of the string, you can use:

```
/(Kenneth Auchenberg)\s*$/
```

Note: there's a typo in your code. The last `Kenneth Auchenberg` is written as `Kenneth Auchenber` (with a missing 'g' at the end).